# Resizing The GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

my question is simple but I can not find exact solution for this. I try to write a program with Java GUI, I use absolute layout for my program and I set frame bounds(100, 100, 450, 300) . When I run the program and make it full screen, components stays on their places. I want them to replace automatically according to screen size.
All supports are accepted, thank you!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use some layout manager: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Actually i try but i cant add two or more buttons one under the other

Comment: @phantom; then you don't understand the layout managers well enough yet. Study the tutorials, nest JPanels each using its own layout manager, and you'll succeed. But avoid null layouts and absolute positioning at almost all costs.

Comment: Thank you for your helps, I'll avoid using null layouts and absolute positioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. You state, `"I use absolute layout for my program and I set frame bounds(100, 100, 450, 300)."` Don't do this. Use the layout managers to help you place your components.

For instance, if you used a BorderLayout for the main JPanel, and added the JButton to a `new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 5)` using JPanel (1 column, variable rows, 5 spaces between rows), adding this JPanel to main in the BorderLayout.LINE_END position, your problem is likely solved. As a general rule, you should avoid use of null layout and use of `setBounds(...)` for component placement as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

Comment: Thank you sir, but how to add two or more buttons to east and one under the other for example...

Comment: @phantom: play with layouts. Use a GridLayout for instance on the east JPanel, and consider nesting it in a BorderLayout using JPanel, placing it at the PAGE_START position, and then place this JPanel into another main JPanel that uses BorderLayout in the BorderLayout.LINE_END position. The key is to keep experimenting.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I get what I want :)